# Can I make a PKCS10 CSR using public key provided by CA server and my own random generated privateKey?

Tags: pkcs#10

I am trying to send a `PKCS10 CSR` request by using `X509` certificate provided by Ca and my own randomly generated `privateKey`.

The request goes fine and I receive a response as well but it throws an exception while decoding the response envelope.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer: The X509 Certificate and private key that we use to enrol a CSR request should belong to same key pair. Any certificate  and a random private key would not work.
The SCEP Client which sends a enrol request to CA server sends the X509 Certificate to the server and then tries to decrypt the CA server response by the private key.

So they should belong to the same keypair.

```
KeyPair kp = generateKeyPair();
X509Certificate tempCert;
EnrollmentResponse er = scepClient.enrol(tempCert, kp.getPrivate(), csr);
```

The above certificate and private key should belong to same keypair.